# Android UI : from html to XML

Tags: android, html, xml, user-interface

I've developped an application using XML Eclipse tool too build my UI. 
Now, i'd like to use a tool like Axure to create a "nicer" interface. 
My problem is : is there an easy way to switch from XML to HTML (because Axure is producting HTML file from Wireframe design) ? 
And if not, how to "plug" HTML file to the existing application (which is using R.layout.xxx or R.id.xxx to access displayed elements).

I'm quite new in Android by the way... 
thanks !

Comment: isn't Axure a prototyping tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do what you describe. The way Android layout is specified in XML cannot be compared at all to HTML for websites. Besides, Axure is a mock-up tool. It creates interactive mockups and prototypes - not final solutions for anything.

If you really want to use Axure, perhaps you would want to go for web apps with something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - they are written in HTML and JavaScript, but have less possibilities.

Comment: So what you're saying is to create a mock-up with Axure, the to convert the HTML design and behavior in an application using PhoneGap and finally plug my existing application to the generated one ?

Comment: PhoneGap is a framework - it will be a part of your application if you choose to do this. But, yes, that's what I'm saying. The other option (that I prefer) is to use Axure purely as a mock-up tool and implement everything natively (using XML, Java, and the Android API).

Comment: So I think i'm gonna stay with the no-so-bad eclipse tool to design my application... Thanks !

Comment: No problem. As an advice, take the time to read through the styling docs - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html - and you could create some really impressive things.